# Why does Ethereum project use custom denominations (e.g. "wei") instead of SI prefix standard (e.g. "microETH", "nanoETH")

Tags: math, wei

What was the reasoning behind reinventing denominations instead of using the [standard metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) for ETH?

10^(-18) ETH = 1 aETH ("attoETH", not "wei")
10^(-9) ETH = 1 nETH ("nanoETH", not "Gwei", *definitely not* "shannon")
10^(-3) ETH = 1 mETH ("milliETH", not "Pwei", *definitely not* "finney"!)
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The wei is named after Wei Dai, best known as the creator of the bitcoin predecessor "b-money" and as the developer of the Crypto++ library.

These units names are defined in the Ethereum whitepaper.

Sources :
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/33
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/wei.asp